# Timing complexity for copy() in python. How do I add the elapsed time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import timeit

def copytest():

lst = []
for i in range(1000000):
    lst.append(i)
starttime = timeit.default_timer()
copiedlst = lst.copy()
endtime = timeit.default_timer()
elapsedtime = endtime - starttime
elapsedtime += elapsedtime
return elapsedtime 

for j in range(1, 100):
    print(j, copytest())
```

I am trying to see how long it takes for copy() to copy a list. It should be O(n) because copy() is going through the list one item at a time. How do I get "elapsedtime" to keep track of the value it has had before? This code resets the elapsed time back to 0. I'd appreciate any help to fixing the code even more also!

Comment: btw, your loop is equivalent to `lst = list(range(1000000))`, but why do you keep re-creating that inside `copytest`?

Comment: Anyway, why don't you just keep adding the result of `copytest()` together? But why exactly do you want to do that? That won't demonstrate anything about time complexity, your *inputs are always the same*

Comment: Do you want to accumulate the `elapsedtime` values or just want to store them somewhere to have access to them?

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate the time complexity for copy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the previous values for `elapsedtime` use the below code. `elapsed_list` holds these values for you.

```
import timeit

def copytest():
  lst = []
  for i in range(1000000):
      lst.append(i)
  starttime = timeit.default_timer()
  copiedlst = lst.copy()
  endtime = timeit.default_timer()
  elapsedtime = endtime - starttime
  elapsedtime += elapsedtime
  return elapsedtime 

elapsed_list = []
for j in range(1, 100):
  e = copytest()
  elapsed_list.append(e)
  print(j, copytest())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import timeit
def copytest(n):
    lst = list(range(1000000))*n
    starttime = timeit.default_timer()
    copiedlst = lst.copy()
    endtime = timeit.default_timer()
    elapsedtime = endtime - starttime
    elapsedtime += elapsedtime
    return elapsedtime 
for j in range(1, 100):
    print(j, copytest(j))
```

This code is able to recognise the complexity of copy command. It is of O(n), where n is the number of elements to copy. The program given in question is basically copying same thing each time and n is not varying; thus, you are getting constant (there are some random variability however, mean are equal) output each time.

Comment: sorry so this code is good enough for checking the complexity of the copy command?

Comment: Yes, it is enough for checking time complexity of copy command. Did it satisfy your requirement? If it did then please accept and upvote. Thanks!